# Service worker registration failed Manifest V3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to make a new extension using manifest V3, this is my first time and I'm getting an error when defining the background.js
here is the error:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUfx7.png)

Comment: As the error message says `window` is not defined. You can't use it in a service worker. If you don't do it in your code, you probably load jQuery or another incompatible library, in which case don't use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the background js using Vue 3, and the manifest wasn't able to read it and apply it, that's why it failed